# Strange ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

what the syntax is in [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) rails guide ?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def welcome_email(user)
      recipients    user.email
      from          "My Awesome Site Notifications <notifications@example.com>"
      subject       "Welcome to My Awesome Site"
      sent_on       Time.now
      body          {:user => user, :url => "http://example.com/login"}
   end
end
```

How should i understand the construction, like

```
from "Some text for this field"
```

Is it an assignment the value to a variable, called "from" ?

Comment: May I ask what kind of application you are developing? It is quite unusual for a Rails developer to encounter his very first receiverless message send in the context of `ActionMailer`. For most Rails developers I know, the first receiverless message sends are `has_many` and `belongs_to` in the context of `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's a method call. The name of the method is `from`, and the argument is a string. In Ruby, parentheses around method calls are optional, so

```
from "Some text for this field"
```

is the same as

```
from("Some text for this field")
```

Rails (and many Ruby libraries) like to express code in a natural language style, though, so the parentheses-less version reads better, hence why it is used in examples.

Answer (score 2):

It is a call to a method `from` with the argument `"Some text for this field"`

The method comes from the `ActionMailer::Base` class that your UserMailer extends from.

In Ruby the parentheses around a method call are optional unless something would be ambiguous so the statement is equivalent to from("Some text for this field")

Rails has a coding style that prefers to be close to natural language where possible, hence not using parentheses unless necessary.

Calling this  method sets an instance variable `@from`  to the  value you  provide so  that it  can be  used later  when sending  the message.

Normally when you have accessor  methods for  getting and  setting a  variable you  would have  `from=` to set the value and `from` to return  the value, however `ActionMailer` uses something  called `adv_attr_accessor` to define the `from`  method so  that if  you call  it with  a parameter then it  acts as a setter but if you call it with no parameters then it acts as a getter.

This can be seen in actionmailer-2.x.x/lib/action_mailer/base.rb and actionmailer-2.x.x/lib/action_mailer/adv_attr_accessor.rb

Answer (score 1):

It's not an assignment. In Ruby, assignments are done using the assignment operator `=` like this:

```
var = val
```

You are probably thinking of some Lisp dialects where assignment looks like this:

```
(def var val)
```

It's just a simple receiverless message send.

In Ruby, the general syntax for a message send is

```
receiver.selector(argument1, argument2)
```

However, if the `receiver` is `self`, you can leave off the `receiver`, so

```
selector(argument1, argument2)
```

is the same as

```
self.selector(argument1, argument2)
```

[Note: this is not quite true. In Ruby, private methods can only be invoked via a receiverless message send, so if in this example `self` responds to the `selector` message by invoking a private method, only the first variant will work, the second will raise a `NoMethodError` exception.]

Also, in cases where there are no ambiguities, you can leave off the parentheses around the arguments like this:

```
receiver.selector argument1, argument2
```

If you put the two things together, you can now see that

```
selector argument1, argument2
```

is equivalent to

```
self.selector(argument1, argument2)
```

and thus

```
from "Some text for this field"
```

is equivalent to

```
self.from("Some text for this field")
```

There is a third shortcut in Ruby's message sending syntax: if the very last argument to a message send is a `Hash` literal, then you can leave out the curly braces. So, the last line in the above example could also be written as

```
  body          :user => user, :url => "http://example.com/login"
```

Also, in Ruby 1.9, a `Hash` literal where all keys are `Symbol`s can be written using an alternative `Hash` literal syntax:

```
 { key1: val1, key2: val2 }
```

is the same as the old syntax

```
{ :key1 => val1, :key2 => val2 }
```

which means that, at least in Ruby 1.9, that last line could also be written as

```
  body          user: user, url: "http://example.com/login"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also call `from` an attribute. It's a property of the email, but how it's implemented is hidden from you (encapsulation). This is a Good Thing. It means that if Rails core decided it's better to change `@from` into several variables, you wouldn't need to change any of your code.